# Prestashop: after making a hook for actionProductAdd and adding the product from the backend it gives an error

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

After making a hook for actionProductAdd then adding the product from backend an error occurs for version 1.7, as below :

> Oops! An Error Occurred The server returned a "500 Internal Server
>   Error". Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing
>   when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry
>   for any inconvenience caused.

Below is my code for module folder file hook

```
<?php

class XyzData extends Module {


    public static $executed = false;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function install() {
        return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('actionProductSave');
    }

    public function uninstall() {

    }

    public function hookActionProductSave($params) {
        echo "Calling function"; exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello turn off and than turn on the Seofriendly URL button. For more detail please see: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/568331-17-cant-access-product/

Comment: Not Working yet

Comment: `allow_url_fopen = On;` in `php.ini`  OR `php_value allow_url_fopen On` in `.htaccess`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create module first and in that module you can call `actionProductSave`. You will find detailed list of hooks available [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.7.x).

For creating module; for e.g ***My Module (my_module)*** you need to follow steps as below.

1) Create folder `my_module` in `modules` directory.

2) Add file `my_module.php` and `logo.png` file in `my_module` directory. `config.xml` file will be created automatically when you install module.

3) Add below code in 'my_module.php' file. You can do your stuffs in function named `hookActionProductSave`. this function will be called every time upon product save.

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class My_Module extends Module
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'my_module';
        $this->author = 'Divyesh Prajapati';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->need_instance = 1;
        $this->tab = 'administration';

        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->trans('My Module', array(), 'Modules.MyModule.Admin');

        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.7.1.0', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
    }

    public function install()
    {
         return parent::install() && $this->registerHook(['actionProductSave']);
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        return parent::uninstall();
    }

    public function hookActionProductSave($params) {
        $product_id = $params['id_product']; // Product Id
        $product = $params['product']; // Product Object

        // Do your stuffs here
    }
}
```

4) Now go to ***Admin > Modules > Modules & Services***; in that go to tab ***Selection*** and find module `my_module` and install it.

5) Now whenever your product will be saved from admin panel; stuffs you have written in `hookActionProductSave` will be called. Please find attached image for array which you get in `$params` array when product will be saved.[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Any idea how to save all products programically? I have weird issue and to resolve it i need to save all products manualy (open, save and close and repeat...) I want to have a simple script that will do it by one click or via CRON... THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

The hook `actionProductSave` is NOT to render content, it's to handle the product data from your side.